# How to get data from date and time range in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, between

MySQL Table: -

```
ID    |    From_DateTime      |    To_DateTime

1          2014-09-01 10:00:00    2014-09-10 22:00:00
```

Explanation:

I have added 2 columns in database table for Date and Time range. The data shown above means that from 01-09-2014 to 10-09-2014 is the date range and 10:00:00 to 22:00:00 is the time range.

**Positive Scenario** - Now I am passing **2014-09-05 15:00:00** in my query which comes into Date and Time both range. What I need is the ID from the query.

**Negative Scenario** - Now I am passing **2014-09-05 23:00:00** in my query which comes into Date comes into range but TIME is not in the specified range so I should get 0 result.

I have no idea about database queries and that is why I am posting it to here to get some help from the database experts.

Comment: Split it to 4 columns: 2 dates and 2 times, since the current schema doesn't make much sense. Then use `DATE()` + `TIME()` functions to compare.

Comment: Using this 2 columns is it not possible to do the match? Is it mandatory to have 4 columns instead of 2? If yes and i split it to 4 columns can you please help me in building query.

Comment: It is possible, but it doesn't make much sense. `datetime` points to the exact point in time, whereas you need a `date` and a `time` which aren't related to each other.

Comment: Can you please tell me how its possible with 2 columns?

Comment: Yeah its done but its giving me null value if no match found. Can you guide me how to avoid that?

Comment: what if you try to debug it yourself? Like you know - do it by small steps and find where exactly it fails. PS: if nothing found mysql returns literally nothing, not `NULL`, since `NULL` **IS** a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.  May need some tweaking.

```
SELECT ID FROM (
  SELECT ID FROM <tablename> 
    WHERE DATE('<dateTimeValue>') BETWEEN DATE(From_DateTime) AND DATE(To_DateTime) 
    AND TIME('<dateTimeValue>') BETWEEN TIME(From_DateTime) AND TIME(To_DateTime)
  UNION
    SELECT 0 AS ID FROM DUAL
) AS a LIMIT 1
```

Comment: If I am passing '2014-09-05 23:00:00'  then also it returns row which is incorrect, I need to match date and time both.

Comment: Gotcha, Editing the above.  You'll need 2 between clauses.

Comment: This is going to slow you down though.  You should take the recommendation above and create 4 columns From_Date, To_Date, From_Time, To_Time so they may be indexed and you don't have to run 6 functions on each row being tested

Comment: One last query, If match does not found its returning NULL. Can we have it like if no match found it should not return NULL.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT id FROM `date_time` 
WHERE From_DateTime < '2014-09-05 15:00:00' 
AND To_DateTime > '2014-09-05 15:00:00';

here `date_time` is table name...
Don't forgot to put date in single quotes